# How to automatically clear cache of Flask-Caching after TIMEOUT interval?

Tags: python, caching, flask-caching

The `Cache` class provides a way for the cache to timeout when caching using `cache.cache(timeout=TIMEOUT)`. But, it doesn't delete the cache automatically after the timeout interval. The only way to clear the cache is by calling `cache.clear()` which clears the entire cache, rather than only the cache of the function that you want to clear.

Is it possible to automatically clear all cache that have timed-out? And are there any other libraries that do so?

Answer (score 0):

Flask-caching doesn't have any mechanism to delete cache/expired cache automatically.

But in `Simple` and `FileSystemCache` mode, it have a `CACHE_THRESHOLD` config setting, if the number of cache more than `threshold` setting, it will delete all expired cache and **every cache that index divisible by three**.

Flask-caching `Simple` mode source code (Version 1.10.1):

```py
    def _prune(self):
        if len(self._cache) > self._threshold:
            now = time()
            toremove = []
            for idx, (key, (expires, _)) in enumerate(self._cache.items()):
                if (expires != 0 and expires <= now) or idx % 3 == 0:
                    toremove.append(key)
            for key in toremove:
                self._cache.pop(key, None)
            logger.debug("evicted %d key(s): %r", len(toremove), toremove)
```

Also, `CACHE_THRESHOLD` can be setting before initializing

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache

config = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "SimpleCache",  
    "CACHE_THRESHOLD": 300 # It can be setting before initializing 
}
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)
```

By and large, if you use these mode, you can write the schedule jobs to delete expired cache like above source code.